# Mod Rewrite problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

.htacces

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ sinj.com.hr/index.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ sinj.com.hr/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ sinj.com.hr/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ sinj.com.hr/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L]


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ sinj.com.hr/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ sinj.com.hr/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ sinj.com.hr/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ sinj.com.hr/$1/$2/$3/$4 [R=301,L]
```

There is folder sinj.com.hr/administracija and when I try to access http://localhost/sinj.com.hr/administracija I am redirected to http://localhost/sinj.com.hr/administracija?var1=administracija
What I would like is when user enters http://localhost/sinj.com.hr/administracija that he is redirected to http://localhost/sinj.com.hr/administracija/index.php. I tried to do this with header("Location:... ") but it always redirects me to http://localhost/sinj.com.hr/administracija?var1=administracija. If folder administracija is renamed then header() function works. Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks,
Ile

Comment: That's no reason to modify the tags. It needs 5 votes to migrate a question to serverfault, but modifying the tags is the decision of just _one_ person which defeats this democratic system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule to test if the request can be mapped to a directory that contains an *index.php* file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.php
```

Additionally you can use this single rule to redirect any requests with a URL path that ends with a slash the one without:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ sinj.com.hr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It works... First time I tried I put it at the end of code... These first two lines must be set before last 4 lines. Uh, you saved my day :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, now there's another problem... For example, if there is folder "vijesti" and it doesn't contain index.php and then if I try to access sinj.com.hr/vijesti I'm redirected to ...vijesti/var1=vijesti ...This time actually I don't need redirection to folder. Any solution for this?